# Is there a way to tell if Oracle attempted an insert on a table from database logs?

Tags: oracle

We have a java application deployed on a production WebSphere server.  The code is supposed to insert a row into a table, but it does not.  I see no error messages in the application server logs.  It is as if no attempt was made to insert the row.  The same code deployed in a test environment does insert the row.

I would like to know if Oracle attempted to insert a row and then rolled it back for some reason.  I am not familiar with Oracle at all.  Is there a way to tell by looking at the database logs if an insert statement was executed on the table?

We are using Oracle 10

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use DML before insert trigger. This trigger will execute each time a row is inserted into the given table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER t_log_insert
 BEFORE INSERT ON table_name
 FOR EACH ROW
 ENABLE
 BEGIN
  --write your logic here.
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('You Just Inserted a Row');
 END;
 /
```

You can read more about trigger [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/).